# How to retrieve com.apple.developer.team-identifier from codesign entitlements programmatically in runtime?

Tags: ios, keychain

using codesign -d --entitlements - path to app
we can see code sign entitlements of .ipa.

for example, Instagram app from AppStore.

```
</array>
 <key>application-identifier</key>
 <string>MH9GU9K5PX.com.burbn.instagram</string>
 <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
 <string>777W53UFB2.com.burbn.instagram</string>
 <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
 <string>777W53UFB2</string>
 <key>aps-environment</key>
 <string>production</string>
 <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment</key>
 <string>Production</string>
 <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
 <array>
```

Is there any way to retrieve com.apple.developer.team-identifier in runtime?

Using this code snippet

```
+ (NSString *)bundleSeedID {
    NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           (__bridge NSString *)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge NSString *)kSecClass,
                           @"bundleSeedID", kSecAttrAccount,
                           @"", kSecAttrService,
                           (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes,
                           nil];
    CFDictionaryRef result = nil;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&result);
    if (status == errSecItemNotFound)
        status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&result);
    if (status != errSecSuccess)
        return nil;
    NSString *accessGroup = [(__bridge NSDictionary *)result objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
    NSArray *components = [accessGroup componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    NSString *bundleSeedID = [[components objectEnumerator] nextObject];
    CFRelease(result);
    return bundleSeedID;
}
```

we will get App Prefix ID (sometimes App Prefix ID may differ from Team ID.

How to get access to com.apple.developer.team-identifier in my app?

Answer (score 0):

This information is stored in the app as `embedded.mobileprovision`, which means that you can read it and extract what you need. It's mostly plist data with some extra data wrapped around it. Once you remove the extra data, you can decode it just like a plist.

This site has more details and good sample code: https://blog.process-one.net/reading-ios-provisioning-profile-in-swift/

Comment: But embedded.mobileprovision is deleted after submission .ipa to AppStore. During development - it's ok.

Comment: App Store apps do not contain an embedded provisioning profile because the App Store checks that the app is signed and provisioned correctly as part of its app ingestion process. -> https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685723