# How to get the TeamID of the Apple Developer Profile from the iPad in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, apple-developer, ipados, apple-developer-account

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms Application: I want to know the iPad's TeamID linked to Apple Developer Profile which will help in creating a work based on the TeamID in order to distinguish from which account the iPad belongs!

As my company is having multiple TeamID's so I need to know from which TeamID the iPad is registered as I need to create a KeychainAccess Group with the name of the TeamID.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630939/how-to-retrieve-com-apple-developer-team-identifier-from-codesign-entitlements-p

Comment: im not quite understand. An app has unique bundleID. How does different team (id) use the same app id?

Comment: So did you mean you want to get the team id for this app in runtime? Team id is ought to be the same.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Yeah correct but the TeamID will be different for different iPads where i need to create a KeychainAcccess Group with the name of that TeamID, So this is the purpose i need to know TeamID.

Comment: okay, but if a device was registered in different team ids. That seems to be another question.